# How to send form data in vue to variable as json using axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios

for now i have method:

```
      let newFormData = {
        productName: this.productName,
        productModel: this.productModel,
        prodDescription: this.prodDescription,
        prodPrice: this.prodPrice,
        promoPrice: this.promoPrice
      };
      console.log(newFormData);
      e.target.reset();
    },
```

and i want to send this form data to file, and save it as a variable in json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first you should have a route to submit this form data to, then you can submit the form like this:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3030/api/new/post', 
    this.productName,
    this.productModel,
    this.prodDescription,
    this.prodPrice,
    { headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    }).then(response => ....);
```